# How do I fix the amplpy error on search path?

Tags: python, amplpy

I have recently installed Amplpy for python 3.6.5 (win 32 bit), but I am facing the following issue:

- Please make sure that the AMPL folder is in the system search path, or   specify the path via:
  AMPL(Environment('full path to the AMPL installation directory'))

---

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1768ae85d3ec> in <module>()
      1 from amplpy import AMPL
----> 2 ampl = AMPL()

D:\Poulad\Program\myprog\lib\site-packages\amplpy\ampl.py in __init__(self, environment, langext)
     83         if environment is None:
     84             try:
---> 85                 self._impl = amplpython.AMPL()
     86             except RuntimeError as e:
     87                 from sys import stderr

RuntimeError: AMPL could not be started: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have also added amplpy and amplpython paths to the search paths through sys.path.append() but the error is poping up again.

Would you please help me to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the path of the ampl executable when you call ampl (line 2). So instead of:

```
ampl = AMPL()
```

you write:

```
ampl = AMPL(Environment('put/here/your/path/'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the `Environment` class from `amplpy`. Then you have to specify where your `amplpy` file is located. It should be something like that:

`from amplpy import AMPL,Environment`

`ampl = AMPL(Environment(r'C:\ampl.mswin64'))`

Comment: This is the right answer. Notice the path must end in a folder like that "ampl.mswin64"